# Set file sharing access and permission to group

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a user who is on a extended leave, I need to set sharing access and permission of the files in the users drive to a group till the user is back.

I used the Admin SDK to pull all the file id's of the user.

What can I use to change all file permission to give the group email edit access?
I used DriveApp but got Access Denied, this could be due to DriveApp being limited to the logged in user.

Are there any other options to complete the above task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [Permissions: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/update).

You can assign the following "[roles](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/update#request-body)" to the users.

- organizer
- owner
- writer
- commenter
- reader

Comment: I have the fileID, when I try to get permission ID using https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/list I get the following 
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
 }
}

I am the domain Admin

Answer (score 1):

I will help you with new method that your mail sent with attach link will display allow!
I preactice win with this code app csript.
Note: send mail use htmlbody.

```
 var url= filepdf.addViewer(emailto).getUrl();
 var bodyhtml = '<a href='+url+'>attachment on bellow;m</a>'
 var subject = [];
 var Emaito = [];       

    MailApp.sendEmail({
                        to: emailto,
                        subject: subject,
                        htmlBody: bodyhtml,
                      });
```